# Use specific RAILS_ENV for a single unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing

I have a specific test I'd like to write to check for regressions.  I've inherited a Rails environment that had no unit tests and there have been very few guards against what is put into the database via external (outside of Rails) means.

The unit test would iterate over a specific model in the database and render a view, ensuring that every instance could still be rendered correctly in that view.  I'd like to run this against a development database instance which is usually a clone of the production database (mysql).

The data is too large to put into fixtures... I'd like to keep the rest of the tests using the 'test' sqlite database.

So - is there a way to override for a single test which database Rails is connected to?

I'm using Rails 3.2.22.

Edit:

Based on [Babar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639751/2077386), I'm using:

```
class MyTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup                                                                     
    @controller = MyController.new                                       
  end                                                                           

  test "should successfully render all" do                            
    begin                                                                       
      connection_config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config()                
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('development')                    
      MyModel.find_each do |i|                                        
        print "#{i.id} - #{i.name}\n"                           
        get(:show, {'name' => i.name})                                  
      end                                                                       
    ensure                                                                      
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(connection_config)                
      # or ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['RAILS_ENV'])                
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

But I get an exception at teardown of trying to rollback.  I assume this is because the test was originally wrapped around a transaction, and since I swapped databases, the connection is now closed and we aren't really in a transaction anymore.

What's the most straight forward workaround?

Edit:

Adding this looks to be the most straightforward:

```
  def setup                                                                     
    @controller = DashboardController.new                                       
    @use_transactional_fixtures = false                                         
  end
```

Comment: Are you using Minitest? Rspec? Something else? I assume you want this test to always use this specific environment and not just do a RAILS_ENV=[x] one off at the command line?

Comment: I want this specific test to always use a specific environment regardless of what RAILS_ENV is set to. ...and actually my test_helper.rb has `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"` set, so I believe RAILS_ENV can't be overridden on the command line?  (which I'm ok with.)

Comment: I seem to have rspec 2.14.1 in my Gemfile, but I think I'm using minitest -- test classes are derived from Test::Unit::TestCase,  ActiveSupport::TestCase, ActionView::TestCase, ActionController::TestCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class method called `establish_connection` which can do what you want. Just connect to a different db while running that specific test using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
```

You can use the database alias from your `database.yml` file. It would be something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('development')
```

You may code it right into your specific test file.

Check the doc: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

Comment: Seriously?  That's all?  I've been looking for days! Thank you so much!  Concurrent with your answer, I also just found http://makandracards.com/makandra/10169-when-connecting-to-a-second-database-take-care-not-to-overwrite-existing-connections which shows also putting an ensure to fallback to the default.  I assume that is necessary?

Comment: I'm getting a rollback error, but I think that may be because I'm derived from ActionController::TestCase.   Test::Unit::TestCase works fine.   I might *need* one of the other test classes, though, in order to simulate page renders?

Comment: I'm more of spec guy than test! Sorry can't answer.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, but note that I've added workarounds in the question for dealing with the transaction wrapped around the test by the rails test framework.